# How to retrieve an output of a Python script using a Java program

Tags: java, python, raspberry-pi

I am having a problem with my code. I have a java class that calls a python script that get gps data. The problem is that I can call the script but I want to return the data to a string on the java side so I can use it in an array later. So basically all I want is to take the data from the python  script and bring it to java as a string and place it in to an array.

**python code**

```
    #! /usr/bin/python
     import os
     from gps import *
     from time import *
     import time
     import threading

     gpsd = None #seting the global variable

     os.system('clear') #clear the terminal (optional)

     class GpsPoller(threading.Thread):
      def __init__(self):
      threading.Thread.__init__(self)
      global gpsd #bring it in scope
      gpsd = gps(mode=WATCH_ENABLE) #starting the stream of info
      self.current_value = None
      self.running = True #setting the thread running to true

 def run(self):
   global gpsd
  while gpsp.running:
  gpsd.next() #this will continue to loop and grab EACH set of gpsd info to clear the     buffer

if __name__ == '__main__':
 gpsp = GpsPoller() # create the thread
try:
  gpsp.start() # start it up
  while True:
    #It may take a second or two to get good data
    #print gpsd.fix.latitude,', ',gpsd.fix.longitude,'  Time: ',gpsd.utc

    os.system('clear')

    print
    print ' GPS reading'
    print '----------------------------------------'
    print 'latitude    ' , gpsd.fix.latitude
    print 'longitude   ' , gpsd.fix.longitude     

    time.sleep(5) #set to whatever

except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit): #when you press ctrl+c
  print "\nKilling Thread..."
  gpsp.running = False
  gpsp.join() # wait for the thread to finish what it's doing
print "Done.\nExiting."
```

**java code**

```
                   Process p4 = null;
                  //String commands4="sudo python test1.py";



                   // provision gpio pin #01 as an output pin and turn on



                    try {




                         p4 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sudo python test1.py");
                         InputStream is = p4.getInputStream();
                         int i = 0;
                         while( (i = is.read() ) != -1) {
                             System.out.print((char)i);
                             lat
                             break;
                         }
```

Comment: Format your code please.

Comment: What particular error/errors are you receiving?

Comment: well i cant python code works but i cant seem figure out how to get the data to be saved in java and the code seem to run but never stos

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check for the `p4.exitCode()` to see if the python script was successfully invoked, and then if it wasn't successful you may check for `p4.getErrorStream()` to see why.

Either way, generally the code should handle different exit codes because you may never be 100% confident that the calling to python script will always be successful.